# How to get a description (comment) of the transaction?

Tags: transactions

From this json response from [blockchain.com](https://blockchain.info/address/6de66adaa2cad5e85647e4e936f4e3708a92f07d?format=json)

How can I get a comment on the translation from here?

[image]

Comment: This sort of description/comment is just stored locally in your wallet for you to see, it is not information that is broadcast publicly.

Comment: How can I get her?
How to get comment if sent via blockchain

Comment: You can not get the description of the transaction, because of the description not is for bitcoin but is for the wallet. How when you give the money for the coffee, you know how you spend your money but not have any description. ps: you don't send the description to blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

The comment field seen on the blockchain.info blockexplorer is a feature of the blockchain.com wallet. The data for that comment field is created by users of their wallet, stored only by blockchain.com/info and published by blockchain.info.

This comment is not part of the Bitcoin transactions stored on the Bitcoin blockchain, it's only stored in the databases of a service by a company called Blockchain. The comment thus cannot be retrieved by other wallets. It may be possible to retrieve it from the blockchain.info API.